# lapply, cbind, and apply within transform

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to use a `lapply` within `transform`.

So this works as expected:

```
dfX1 = data.frame(a = rpois(100, 10), 
           b = rpois(100, 10))
dfX2 = transform(dfX1, c = a %in% c(6, 7))
```

However, when I try something like:

```
dfX3 = transform(dfX1, 
                 c = apply(
                   do.call('cbind', 
                           lapply(c(a, b), 
                                  function(x) x %in% c(6, 7))), 1, sum))
```

I get the weird result:

```
> head(dfX3)
   a  b  c
1  9  9 26
2  9  8 26
3  6  7 26
4  9 11 26
5 11  9 26
6 11 16 26
```

My expectation is that the `lapply` would return a list of vectors that would be coerced into a matrix by `cbind`, and the `apply` would apply the function `sum` across rows.

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I think replacing `c(a, b)` by `list(a, b)` will solve your problem.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot It does! But why?

Comment: Because `c(a, b)` is a vector containing the values in `a` and then the values in `b`. What you want is to apply your function to `a` and `b`, so you need a list.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot Ah, I get it. Because of what happens when the vector gets coerced to a list.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot Yes, put your comment in as an answer, and you have my points. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the problem comes from `c(a, b)`, which is the concatenation of cols `a` and `b`. The result will be the number of values that are either equal to 6 or 7 in both `a` and `b`, repeated along the lines.

Replacing c(a, b) by list(a, b) gives the correct result.

Also, a more synthetic way or doing this is

```
transform(dfX1, c= apply( data.frame(a,b), 1, function(u) sum(u %in% 6:7)) )
```